# how to upload a xlsx file in plumber api as a input

Tags: r, api, plumber

> I want an api which can upload a xlsx file,which select by the
> user.The api should take any xlsx file as a input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#* @post /upload_excel
#* @param f:file
#* @param sheet:str
#* @param range:str
function(f, sheet, range) {

  tmp <- tempfile("plumb", fileext = paste0("_", basename(names(f))))
  on.exit(unlink(tmp))
  writeBin(f[[1]], tmp)
  t <- readxl::read_excel(tmp, sheet, range)
  nrow(t)
}
```

Comment: How to read it as .xlsx after taking input?

Comment: I mean I want to access one column of that excel file.

Comment: From https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/681#issuecomment-700318254. you can use `readxl::read_xlsx` instead. See the doc for more information.